# Create canvas imageData from base64 JPEG image without using image object

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am experiencing a problem in reading JPEG base64 image into canvas imageData. The generated canvas image is garbled with black and white pixels (junk image).

I want to achieve this without using image object or any additional BLOBs.

Reading base64 JPEG image data through fileReader and trying to create canvas image.

```
var img, bytes, arr, bytes, binary_string,i, uri = base64String;
img = context.createImageData(400, 300);                
binary_string =  window.atob(uri.slice(uri.indexOf(',')+1));
arr = binary_string.split('').map(function (e) {return e.charCodeAt(0);});
bytes = new Uint8ClampedArray(arr);
for (i=0; i<bytes.length; i+=1) {
   img.data[i] = bytes1[i];
}
```

Please share your thoughts and experiences.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you insist on doing it without an Image object? Using a Base64 encoded Jpeg stream and interpreting as if it were a bitmap is not going to work, because Jpeg is a heavily compressed image format. You need to decode the Jpeg data before you can use it. An Image object makes the users web browser do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response Philipp. I have tried using image object and noticed that a copy of base64 JPEG image retained in the browser memory, which is causing mobile safari to crash.